# Sending a POST with mechanize and requests.

Tags: python, csrf, python-requests, mechanize-python, twill

I am trying to send a POST using mechanize however my code won't work sometimes(and I know why). I have used mechanize, twill and requests. With  mechanize and twills it is working and with requests it is not. Probably I am doing it in wrong way.

My mechanize code. The following works :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import urllib
import mechanize
from mechanize import ParseResponse, urlopen, urljoin
response = urlopen(url)
forms = ParseResponse(response, backwards_compat=False)
form = forms[0]
form["username"] = "avi"
form["password"] = "stackoverflow"
urlopen(form.click())
```

My twill code. It also works :

```
import os
import twill
from twill.commands import *
out = open(os.devnull,"w")
twill.set_output(out)
go(url)
formvalue("1", "username", "avi")
formvalue("1", "password", "stackoverflow")
submit()
go(url2) #some protected page
content = show()
print 'content is',content[:100]
```

From what I understand, mechanize or twill first gets the page, fills the form and sends the form. But problem here is, sometimes target page displays random page, without any form. In that case I get an error, obviously because there is no form to show. I don't want to handle this error, because I already know the post URL. even though some random page is displayed, after I click next, same form is loaded. The POST url, fields all remain same. So I wanted to send the POST request directly, since I already know details everything required. Here is my code, [based on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6894179/1382297) :

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()
parameters = {"username" : "avi",
          "password" : "stackoverflow",
         }  
data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
browser.open(post_url,data)
cool = browser.open(post_url + '%s' % data).read()
print cool
```

I get an error :

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused>
```

I tried same thing with requests. But I am getting same error as above. Here is the code :

```
import requests
from requests import session
payload = { 'username': 'avi','password': 'stackoverflow'}
url1 = 'http://example.com/login.php'
url2 = 'http://example.com/protected.php'

with session() as c:
    c.post(url1, data=payload)
    c.get(url2)
```

So I poked here and there, read few more code available online and I think it is not working because to prevent CSRF. So I went to same page with twill, did showforms and saw there is some value with token :

[image]

Here is what I want :

1. Do POST with mechanize and requests (without downloading the page first)
2. How to handle CSRF tokens ?
3. How to debug 'urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused'

Answer (score 6):

I've used the code below with success:

```
params = {u'user_login': self.USER, u'password':self.PASSWORD}
data = urllib.urlencode(params)
request = mechanize.Request( loginURL )
response = mechanize.urlopen(request, data=data)
```

To handle the CSRF token issue, I added the line below to my controller:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:create]
```

To keep the session between requests, I use a cookiesJar. But you can retrieve the CSRF token from your request and keep it in your application, adding it the each new request.

Comment: What to you mean with: "I added ... to my controller"?

Answer (score 2):

You **have to** retrieve the form page in order to get the session cookies and the csrf token.

The connection refused error might be due you got blocked by the site due to posting to the login page through automated means.

Comment: @avi sounds like your IP got blocked. You should try from another host or obtaining a new IP (i.e. resetting your adsl router).

Comment: I tried, but no success. And also my other code with twill is working fine

Comment: It might be user agent. Did you tried to change the user agent to one of a known browser? `requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': '...'})`.

Comment: yes, I also tried with user-agent also. Here is the code : http://pastie.org/8368647

Comment: That's really odd. Does it work a simple GET with curl/wget? Is twill using a proxy or something? Is the python code not running through a proxy?

Comment: No it is not working with curl also. I got 'curl: (7) couldn't connect to host' where as I can open the site in browser fine. Twill not using any proxy. I did not configure any proxy in twill.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38383/discussion-between-rho-and-avi)